# create columns from another using condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have columns like Vendor and stores .vendor has values like amazon,lowes,walmart and stores includes NYC,WDC,CAL etc.
I want two columns i.e amazon_stores and otherVendor_stores.
amazon_stores will have values of all amazon's stores
and otherVendor_stores will have values of other vendor's stores.

Comment: A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would increase your chances of getting a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simple use of `np.where()` from what you have described

```
vendor = "amazon,lowes,walmart".split(",")
stores = "NYC,WDC,CAL".split(",")
df = pd.DataFrame([{"vendor":v, "stores":s} for v in vendor for s in stores ])

df = df.assign(
    amazon_store=lambda x: np.where(x["vendor"]=="amazon", x["stores"], ""),
    othervendor_store=lambda x: np.where(x["vendor"]!="amazon", x["stores"], ""),
)
```

**output**

```
  vendor stores amazon_store othervendor_store
  amazon    NYC          NYC                  
  amazon    WDC          WDC                  
  amazon    CAL          CAL                  
   lowes    NYC                            NYC
   lowes    WDC                            WDC
   lowes    CAL                            CAL
 walmart    NYC                            NYC
 walmart    WDC                            WDC
 walmart    CAL                            CAL
```